# How can I force an azure Web app to re-pull its container?

Tags: azure-container-registry, azure-web-app-for-containers

I have pushed a container update to a private ACR.  My webapp is configured with the registry's admin credentials, and to pull the image tagged "latest".  According to Step 2 in Part 6 of this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/tutorial-vscode-docker-node/tutorial-vscode-docker-node-06

> *Restarting an app service automatically pulls the latest container image from the registry.*

This is not happening for me. When I go to the portal and restart the app service nothing happens.  The deployment logs reflect the last time the app successfully deployed which was over a month ago. I can verify that the image was successfully updated in the registry.

Is there some other way I can force the service to re-pull and launch the container?  Are there any logs I could use to troubleshoot issues connecting to and pulling from the ACR?

Comment: Are you sure you have run both the 'Docker Images: Build Image' & 'Docker Images: Push'? 
When you browse (in the Azure Portal) to your ACR and open the repo, do you see the new time stamp from around the time you did the push?

From the webapp, select the Deployment Center and then logs. Do you see that it is pulling the container?

Have you tried to restart the web app?

Comment: Yes, the ACR logs reflect the new timestamp of my most recent push.  However, when I restart the app the deployment logs don't show any attempt to pull- they only show timestamps from the last successful deployment in March. If I ftps into the deployment I only see the boilerplate hostingstart.html in wwwroot.  Maybe the deployment is failing to authenticate to the ACR but if so I can't find any logs indicating this.

Answer (score 3):

Verify the connnectivity between the the azure webapp for conatiners and ACR in deployment center.
[image]
And make sure the password in app service configuration settings is correct. I faced the same when I have tested with wrong password after the initial deployment to web app.

[image]

Enable continuous deployment for seamless deployment on azure app service deployment and copy the webhook URL.
[image]

Configure webhook in container registry as below.

[image]

[image]

Once, we configured webhook connection, no need to restart the app service to pull the latest image from ACR. Whenever a new image version pushed to ACR, azure web app will automatically pull the image. It will take 2 to  5 mins to serve requests. While testing, try to browse in incognito tab to see changes immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Unfortunately I'm still struggling with this workflow. Last night I accidentally pushed a bad container. The service couldn't launch and left this message in the logs: "2023-07-04T04:43:06.305Z INFO - Stopping site t4t-annotation-api-prod because it failed during startup."  With the webhook disabled I pushed a new image and tried restarting the service multiple times, to no effect.  I enabled the webhook and pushed a new image, and the acr logs now show a 406 error: {"Error":"Excessive SCM Site operation requests. Retry after 5 seconds"}.

Comment: And then all of a sudden the service is pulling the container. Maybe I just need to leave a comment here whenever it's stuck. :/